# hide div based on specific simple-form option value

Tags: jquery, show-hide, simple-form, html-select

I'm trying to hide a div based a specific value in a dropdown, however I'm using the rails gem 'simple-form' which seems to be giving me trouble.

```
    <td><%= f.input :field_type, collection: %w{text_field check_box drop_down}, wrapper_html: { id: 'dropdown' } %>
    <td class="selectobject"><%= f.link_to_add "Add Selection Option", :field_options %>

var form = $('#dropdown');
form.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'drop_down') {
        $('.selectobject').hide();
    }
    else $('.selectobject').show();
});
```

When 'drop_down' is selected I want the "selectobject" class to be hidden, so I'm using this jQuery code to hide it, but this doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd start by debugging. Does the JS function get called when the dropdown is selected? Is `$(this).val()` indeed equal to 'drop_down' etc.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var form = $('#dropdown');
form.change(function () {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if ($selected.val() === 'drop_down') {
        $('.selectobject').hide();
    } else { $('.selectobject').show(); }
});
```